# Use of git tags in package.json (for git dependencies)

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

Is it possible some how to get update behaviour for git dependencies a like for NPM packages?

So I have git dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-module": "github:me/my-module"
}
```

And want it be updated each time I do `npm install`, adding revision hash is solution but requires more work to track and update in `package.json` each time package is update on Github.

There are also git tags (which also can be set using `npm version` command - it creates commit with tag `v1.2.3`. Is there is way to use these tags in dependencies in `package.json`?

git tag on repo gives me:

```
v1.0.1  
v1.0.0
```

If I try to add in `package.json` after module name version like: #1.0.0 or #v1.0.1

````
```
"dependencies": {
"my-module": "github:me/my-module#1.0.1"
}
```
````

Install fails with error:

```
Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true rev-list -n1 1.0.0
fatal: ambiguous argument '1.0.0': unknown revision or path not in the
ree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'


If you need help, you may report this error at:
    <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Comment: If `git tag` gives you values like `v1.0.0` etc, then you need to use that exact value. Using `1.0.0` **will fail**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done like this

`"my-module": "git+https://github.com/user/repo.git#v1.2.3"`

Comment: This does work, have you definitely pushed your tags up to github? `git push --follow-tags` Is your tag name correct?

Comment: Thanks right, But there is no poisibility to have something like `#^v1.0.0` and have utomatic updates for patches/minor versions?

Comment: Yep no semver support unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for semver support for git dependencies, I am afraid you are out of luck.

When installing git dependencies, npm allows you to specify one of the following to control what particular commit you whish to install as a dependency:

- commit (full sha1 string of the commit)
- commit (short commit string)
- branch
- tag

The format is defined as follows:

*package.json:*

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "some-dep": "username/reponame#commit-ish"
  }
}
```

Where `commit-ish` is one of the items listed above.

Attempting to use one of the semver modifiers when specifying `commit-ish` will fail, ie. `#~1.2.3` is not a valid `commit-ish`. [See the docs for yourself](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

I tried using git+ssh but didn't work. Finally this worked for me for repo in bitbucket

```
"my-module": "git+https://bitbucket.org/repos/myrepo/#0.1.0"
```